# Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided requires using 'export type'.ts

Tags: typescript

I have created multiple interfaces and want to ship them all from a common `index.ts` file as shown below:

```
--pages
------index.interface.ts
--index.ts
```

Now In my `index.ts` I am exporting something like:

```
export { timeSlots } from './pages/index.interface';
```

whereas my `index.interface.ts` look like this:

```
export interface timeSlots {
  shivam: string;
  daniel: string;
  jonathan: string;
}
```

Now when I try to do so, it says me:

`Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided requires using 'export type'.ts(1205)`

Not sure why this error shows up, can someone help?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You just need to use this syntax when re-exporting types:

```ts
export type { timeSlots } from './pages/index.interface';
//     ^^^^
// Use the "type" keyword
```

Or, if using a version of TypeScript >= `4.5`, you can use the [`type` modifier](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5/#type-on-import-names) before *each* exported type identifier instead:

```ts
export { type timeSlots } from './pages/index.interface';
//       ^^^^
// Use the "type" keyword
```

---

The second approach allows you to mix *type* and *value* identifiers in a single `export` statement:

```ts
export { greet, type GreetOptions } from './greeting-module';
```

Where `greeting-module.ts` might look like this:

```ts
export type GreetOptions = {
  name: string;
};

export function greet(options: GreetOptions): void {
  console.log(`Hello ${options.name}!`);
}
```

Comment: How would I do this in an AWS Code build environment? For example, I am getting this error from a library, and upon installation, it offers this typescript error.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416680/re-exporting-a-type-when-the-isolatedmodules-flag-is-provided-requires-using/70417066#comment132461117_70417066) @Luke You can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if it's still relevant (and feel free to link it here in a comment if desired).

Comment: but why does it require us to do so? Why can't it automatically recognize it's a type?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416680/re-exporting-a-type-when-the-isolatedmodules-flag-is-provided-requires-using/70417066?noredirect=1#comment135368602_70417066) @Ooker **Identifiers** can be _values_, _types_, or [both](https://tsplay.dev/w1kRKm) — and need to be statically-analyzed for compilation- and tree-shaking-purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [official documentation for type-only exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export).

> This feature is something most users may never have to think about; however...
>
> ...`export type` only provides an export that can be used for type contexts, and is also erased from TypeScript’s output.

To fix the issue, update your code to this:

```
export type { timeSlots } from './pages/index.interface';
```

Answer (score 3):

you can change `true` to `false` for `isolatedModules` in your source project `tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "isolatedModules": false,  //true to false
    ...
  }
}
```