# How to export deps in DENO?

Tags: typescript, deno

I would like to know how I can export npm modules as express
For example, I have the following import, it works fine and the linter does not show any errors:

`import express, { Request, Response } from 'npm:express';`

however when taking it to my deps.ts I get the following error:

`export express, { Request, Response } from 'npm:express';`

Error:

`';' expected.`

try to separate it but it gives another error:

`export express from 'npm:express'; export { Request, Response } from 'npm:express';`

Error:

`Unexpected keyword or identifier`

Then try the following:

`import express from 'npm:express'; export { Request, Response } from 'npm:express'; export { express };`

but i get the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'npm:express' does not provide an export named 'Request' export { Request, Response } from 'npm:express';`

**and I don't know how to solve it, I hope you can help me, I don't want to use a default import in my app.ts file, I hope you can help me**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default export from the [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) package is a [function](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a6b57ed5f511b6d1c842b6acb4961c966d4afb00/types/express/index.d.ts#L27), but [`Request`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a6b57ed5f511b6d1c842b6acb4961c966d4afb00/types/express/index.d.ts#L112) and [`Response`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a6b57ed5f511b6d1c842b6acb4961c966d4afb00/types/express/index.d.ts#L127) are type [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces).

When exporting types, you should [use the `type` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417066/438273), like this:

`./deps.ts`:

```ts
export { default as express, type Request, type Response } from "npm:express";
```

Then, those exported dependencies can be imported into another module like this:

`./mod.ts`:

```ts
import { express, type Request, type Response } from "./deps.ts";

console.log("typeof express:", typeof express); // typeof express: function
```

You can then run the `mod.ts` module in the terminal and see this output:

```txt
% deno --version
deno 1.29.4 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.9.194.5
typescript 4.9.4

% deno run --allow-env --allow-read mod.ts
typeof express: function
```