# How do I use Express as a dependency, in deps.ts

Tags: typescript, express, deno

Following the example to use Express with Deno:

```
// @deno-types="npm:@types/express@4.17.15"
import express from "npm:express@4.18.2";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to the Dinosaur API!");
});

app.listen(8000);
```

I want to [put the dependencies in "deps.ts"](https://deno.land/manual@v1.35.1/examples/manage_dependencies)

But two issues arise:

A) How do I "export" the express namespace in the deps.ts? This does not work:

[image]

B) How do I "export" the type declarations? I assume they should go in a dev_deps.ts file? Do I only put the `// @deno-types="npm:@types/express@4.17.17"` line in that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing `express` in module code (ESM), it is the [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export). So, to export it, the syntax is:

```ts
// @deno-types="npm:@types/express@4.17.17"
export { default as express } from "npm:express@4.18.2";
//       ^1         ^2
// 1. Identifier of original export
// 2. The re-exported alias (name)
```

To [re-export types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417066/438273) from the associated `@types/express` package, you can simply export the types from that package:

`./deps.ts`:

```ts
// @deno-types="npm:@types/express@4.17.17"
export { default as express } from "npm:express@4.18.2";

export type {
  Application,
  RouterOptions,
  // etc.
} from "npm:@types/express@4.17.17";
```

Then, you can use those exports in another module like this:

`./main.ts`:

```ts
import { type Application, express } from "./deps.ts";

const app: Application = express();

console.log(typeof app); // "function"
```

This is the terminal output:

```txt
% deno check main.ts
Check file:///Users/deno/so-76719582/main.ts

% deno run --allow-env --allow-read=. main.ts
function
```

---

However, in the case of express, the types are all available on the `express` identifier — it serves as both a [functional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) namespace for **values**, and a [(TypeScript) namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) for **types** — so you can skip exporting the types separately:

`./deps.ts`:

```ts
// @deno-types="npm:@types/express@4.17.17"
export { default as express } from "npm:express@4.18.2";
```

`./main.ts`:

```ts
import { express } from "./deps.ts";

const app: express.Application = express();

console.log(typeof app); // "function"
```

The output remains the same:

```txt
% deno check main.ts
Check file:///Users/deno/so-76719582/main.ts

% deno run --allow-env --allow-read=. main.ts
function
```

The version of Deno being used for the code in this answer:

```txt
% deno --version
deno 1.35.1 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 11.6.189.7
typescript 5.1.6
```

> If you're interested in learning more about the above ideas, see the TS handbook section [Namespaces and Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html), and [here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgSwE4FNhQeGBeGBvAKBhgFUAHALhgCIBXM6gGiJgCUEBzACyiuqU48mLOCADuYPgBNxYYcQAyKAGa8aAGxVRhAXxgBDCDFCQoAbgIEoATzIp4yNBiy4bdkMoep0mMAG0AaxRrDxg3FFDEb2cwAF0LYhgAeiSAPQB+S2VaMB8sMgEwKCinXwAKKUc8yS9S8ABKKgA3EAQpfBYTCBBNADp1EA4ygAMAcVawDhgAEjxK6N8dAEJh+osdSwKEIpLqst2Y3vI15KSace2p+iXqAiA) of the same identifier being used for a value and for a type.

Comment: FWIW: I opened [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7281) on this topic back in 2020, and it was being assigned to future milestones for a while, but it seems like the core team lost track of it somewhere along the way. However, it seems like maybe it's actually fixed now and just needs to be closed? 